# Ibn sina,emanationism,the creed of the sufis and Ibn A'rabi?

Tags: sufism

Ibn sina believes two things wich are problematic to me:

1.that there is emanationism  of Allah(aj) in creation like the neoplatonics,thru his single eternal act of self knowing wich is eternal.

wich to me would imply that creation is eternal.wich to me is problematic and it also implies we are Allah,doesn't it?

this also is used by ibn sina to explain why a absolutely one cause can create a multiplicity of effects,as philosophers like Vasubandhu have criticized this to 'prove'that Allah(aj)doesn't or cannot be the creator of the universe.

2.that all possibilities are realized necasserily by Allah(aj)
he bases this on his understanding of absolute Divine simplicity.
what is the creed of the sufis in regards to this(emanationism of Allah in creation,wich would make it eternal) and do the sufis follow A'shari,maturidi or ibn A'rabi in Aqeedah?what is Ibn A'rabi's stance on this,and what is his account of Allah's simplicity,his tawheed and his role in creation?

I do believe in divine simplicity because to me it means absolute tawheed and vice versa,and I also am from a trinitarian backround with a latin eternal modalistic model so I was led to islam by understanding Aquinas,and taking it to the conclusions that his catholic presuppositions prevented him from reaching Vis-a-vis the Trinity.

but I heard that al-Ghazali spoke against absolute divine simplicity?if I believe in absolute divine simplicity am I still a orthodox muslim?or am I outside the pale of islam?

Comment: One of the basics of Sunni orthodox Islam is that we deny ADS because it entails denial of God having attributes. This goes against the face of both the Quran and the Sunnah. Sufis are almost all Sunni.

Comment: Ibn Sina actually was not Sunni.

Comment: ibn Arabi had been declared a zindeeq

Comment: @The Z ,how can a being who's essence and existance being identical,and thus the only thing that is uncreated,and pure being itself as hamza yusuf has said the sunnis beleive about Allaah(aj)not be absolutely simple?and how can this being not have parts?and if you believe Allaah is not simple,how is he absolutely one and why do you say trinity is impossible or shirk if its the Latin model for example?I'm genuinely curious and need some help.

Comment: @johnyman You should come to chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135570/ads

Answer (score -1):

Ibn Arabi is known for the concepts unity of being (wahdatul wujd), I know this wasn't a direct answer to your question but you might get some clue on what his actual stance

God is unique meaning there's nothing like him, emanationism of Allah in creation most of us reject this